# Java - How to parse XML with endless recursive structure?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, recursion, xml-parsing

i have a question regarding xml parsing.

I want to develop a Java DOM parser(or any other in java) able to parse an xml with a structure such as below:

```
<root>
    <parameters>
        <parameter> <!-- ParameterA -->
            <name>a</name>
            <values> <!-- possible values for ParameterA -->
                <value>
                    <name>a1</name>
                    <parameter> <!-- ParameterB dependent of ParameterA -->
                        <name>a11</name>
                        <values> <!--possible values for ParameterB -->
                            <value>
                                <name>a111</name>
                            </value>
                            <value>
                                <name>a112</name>
                            </value>
                        </values>
                    </parameter>
                </value>
                <value>
                    <name>a2</name>
                    <parameter> <!-- ParameterC dependent of ParameterA -->
                        <name>a22</name>
                        <values> <!--possible values for ParameterC -->
                            <value>
                                <name>a222</name>
                            </value>
                        </values>
                    </parameter>
                </value>
            </values>
        </parameter>
        <parameter> <!-- ParameterX -->
            <name>b</name>
            <values> <!-- possible values for ParameterX -->
                <value>
                    <name>b1</name>
                </value>
            </values>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
</root>
```

To resume the xml strucutre:

- A parameter has a name and a list of possible values (a parameter may have no values).
- A value has name and can contain parameters.

**example**:

if a ParameterB is dependent of a ParameterA, then, parameterA will have inside his value tag a parameter tag that will have the information regarding parameterB etc...

I want my Dom Parser to be able to retrieve all parameter combinations according to the xml hierarchy (with respect to their values).

For the example above, the Dom Parser should return

```
>> a-a1-a11-a111-b-b1
>> a-a1-a11-a112-b-b1
>> a-a2-a22-a222-b-b1
```

I dont know if this is possible, i've been knocking my head for days over this...

Thank you,

Please dont hold back on suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursive data structure, so the obvious approach is to make your DOM "parser" recursive too.  In fact, you have no real alternative if you use a DOM-based extractor.

However, I think your problem is that you are trying to do two things at the same time these are:

- find all of the possible values for each parameter
- form the set of all possible combinations of those values

If you do the two tasks separately, it be easier to code.